Exposing Unreal DataAsset in plugin config
I would like to expose some DataAsset in the configuration of my plugin.
If I wanted some integer, this would work well:
UPROPERTY(Config, EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Some asset")
int Foo;

But If I go for
UPROPERTY(Config, EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Some asset")
UFoo* Foo;

where
UCLASS()
class UFoo: public UDataAsset

then I get the error message:

error : Not allowed to use 'config' with object variables

Is there anyway to benefit from the nice UI features of UDataAsset, while exposing them in the settings?

UObject pointers are not allowed to be used with Config. You should use FSoftObjectPath instead with the AllowedClasses metadata.
your property should look something like this:
UPROPERTY(Config, EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Some asset", meta=(AllowedClasses="DataAsset"))
FSoftObjectPath Foo;

Reference: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/not-allowed-to-use-config-with-object-variables/492507/2
